# Why might Eclipse failing to identify fields?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I have got four lines of code in the class "Main".

```
static boolean cantConnect = false;
static boolean taken = false;
static boolean con = false;
static boolean start = false;
```

In the class "Terrain", I want to modify one of these variables.

If I type "Main." in that class, I get a load of options, including the "start" variable, but I get zero results when scrolling down or pressing "C" when I want to get the variable "con" (Should be 2 results with C).

A restart of Eclipse fixes the issue, and all variables now show up perfectly, however it is really annoying and I would really love to know how to fix it.

Just to clarify, even if I do type in the variable name correctly (I even copy-pasted the name) it still acts as if it is not fixed, giving me the "Quick fix" of creating the variable. 
The funny thing is, if I actually click the button to create the variable I then of course get the red line saying that there are two things of the same name, meaning that Eclipse surely must know that the variable of that name is indeed there.

Comment: Can you show us [complete, minimal example code that demonstrates the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Something on the order of 2 classes and 10 lines that suffice to produce the problem when copied into source files with no other code in them?

Comment: Do any of these fields have visibility modifiers? Things like `public`, `private`, or `protected`?

Comment: you say that a restart fixed this issue. when does it reappear?

Comment: @Nivas Usually when I make new variables in one class and attempt to get them from another class. However, it sometimes works and sometimes does not.

Comment: @user2357112 Since a restart fixed it, then giving you the same code would actually be 100% useless, as you would be unable to duplicate the problem.

I copy-pasted the code into the OP exactly how they were in the IDE.

Comment: Also, whoever edited it - You're wrong. It is not an issue with only static variables only, and Eclipse acts as if it does not exist, it is not only an issue with the content assistor.

I edited in a more appropriate title.

Comment: @user3779420 That edit wouldn't have happened if you picked a proper title from the start.

Comment: I am wondering: You mention 2 classes. Those classes are in different files I believe. Restarting the application requires you to save. Does this issue solve itself when you save the changes without restarting the application?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe disabling "Build automatically" could have a similar effect, i.e. the variable not being known until the next rebuild.

Comment: @Sumurai8 If I click the "Save-all" button after doing a change, the issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hit or miss answer, but SAVING the project will remove fake errors, that the compiler seems to "forget" to remove.

Say, I have a complex code, and I need to change one variable's type, that leads me to have to change other code to compensate for this different type, when finished, sometimes I still have errors, when there shouldn't be. Saving the project will re-analyze the code, and remove false errors.

Comment: Unfortunatley saving or refreshing does not work. That said, may be useful to people in future as I have seen problems like this able to be solved by saving.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer I found, this is related to auto complete, also fixed by restart but there was a final fix for it in the settings:
https://superuser.com/questions/209752/eclipse-doesnt-autocomplete-and-find-references-anymore

Depending on your version of eclipse, this may or may not be it, this was related to the Kepler version

Also, try Build -> clean -> check all, save, reopen, run. And see if it continues.